# How to stop kafka connect service

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm aware, that the kafka server can be shutdown using shell script **kafka-server-stop.sh** and zookeeper can be shutdown using  **zookeeper-server-stop.sh**

But, how do we stop **connect-distributed.sh** gracefully, I didn't find any stop shell script for connect-distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a stop script.

Best options other than `kill` command would be to use `systemctl` to manage the service, or use pre-built Docker images to run the server that can be stopped.